# SQL: full outer join between two dates

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows:

```
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ date ┆ id  ┆ v   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1    ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 2    ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ 2    ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 3    ┆ 3   ┆ 5   │
│ 3    ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I wonder if and how can I do a conditional join with itself based on date and id. The requirements are:

1. inner join on left.date = right.date + 1
2. outer join on left.id = right.id

The desired result would be:

```
date_left date_right id_left id_right v_left v_right
    2         1        NULL     1      NULL    1
    2         1         2       2       3      2
    2         1         3      NULL     4     NULL
    3         2        NULL     2      NULL    3
    3         2         3       3       5      4
    3         2         4      NULL     6     NULL
```

Comment: …I don’t see any dates, just integers.

Comment: Your question title says "full outer join" but your description is an inner join with a left (?) outer join. A little confusing.

Comment: Please ready this document on how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    coalesce(l.date, r.date + 1) as date_left,
    coalesce(r.date, l.date - 1) as date_right,
    l.id as id_left, r.id as id_right,
    l.v as v_left, r.v as v_right
from (select * from T where date > (select min(date) from T)) l
     full outer join
     (select * from T where date < (select max(date) from T)) r
         on r.id = l.id and l.date = r.date + 1
order by date_left, date_right, coalesce(l.id, r.id);
```

Instead of filtering prior to the full join, you could also move that logic into a `where` clause. Refer to fiddle for example.

https://dbfiddle.uk/x3mnMb-h